# How to add multiple ingress rules in a security group via shell script on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to add rules for 100 IPs to a security group by running a shell script on EC2 instance.

```
   aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --protocol tcp --port 9997 --cidr ${fixed_ips} --group-id $group_ids
```

I am getting below error, though I have admin access :

```
An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message:
```

Comment: What exactly are your bash varieties?

Comment: The fixed_ips is the IP address that i want to add in the security group and group_id is the id of the security group

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-not-auth-launch/

Comment: @Marcin : Not resolved yet. Is there any way to achieve the goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error writes:

```
You are not authorized
```

which means you have no permissions to perform `authorize-security-group-ingress` operation. You have to double check your IAM user/role and any SCPs that you may be subjected to, to ensure you have permissions to perform the operation in question. This can include using the wrong region.

Update:

If the code runs on EC2 instance you have to setup [Instance Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) with the needed permissions.

Comment: But I already have admin access, which covers all operations. Not sure what else must I add. The region is correct as well.

Comment: @Shivani Is the account part of some AWS organization? Do you run the command form an EC2 instance? Did you verify that you are actually using correct IAM user to run the command?

Comment: no, not part of AWS org. Yes, running the command from EC2 instance. Yes, I am using correct IAM user

Comment: @Shivani When you are using EC2 instance, Instance role is used to access AWS servics, not your IAM user which can be admin.